# Pytest patch staying in other test classes

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project structure with `/src` and `/test` directories.

The first executed test is `/test/kernel_application_test.py`

In there, I create a test class

```py
@mock.patch('customlib.snowflake.SnowFlakeConnector', autospec=True)
class TestExecuteApplication(unittest.TestCase):
```

Then another class gets executed: `/test/sql_loader_test.py`

inside that class, the `customlib.snowflake.SnowFlakeConnector` is imported, with no patches. Note that the tests in `/test/sql_loader_test.py` I create another class that inherits from unittest.TestCase.

If I run `pytest /test/sql_loader_test.py`, the test runs correcly, but when I run `pytest`, the tests inside `/test/sql_loader_test.py` execute later and sees SnowFlakeConnector as a mock, even if it's not defined there as a patch. If I print the object I get:

`<NonCallableMagicMock name='SnowFlakeConnector()' spec='SnowFlakeConnector' id='5159517536'>`

Note that the id is the same as the printed in `/test/kernel_application_test.py`, but I don't understand how a patch applied to one test affects other test. My guess was that with the patch decorator the patch was removed after the class was executed, but seems to not be the case

Comment: Because you are mocking it at the class level, it will persist throughout your tests. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#applying-the-same-patch-to-every-test-method) on that. It will explain what is happening. Also, you mentioned pytest, but your tests seem to be structured under the unittest structure. What is your intention? Because in pure pytest you can make use of fixtures where you can scope them explicitly and then bring them in to each method accordingly.

Comment: From my understanding you are telling me that if i create a patch for a test class, ALL my test classes will receive that patch? Not only the test class I create the tests in? The problem I have is that I define a patch in TestExecuteApplication and the patch exists in any other class inside any other file in the tests (if executed after the TestExecuteApplication)

Comment: The documentation linked [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#applying-the-same-patch-to-every-test-method) explains the scope of what is going on when you set the patch at the test class level.

Answer (score 0):

When I use mock with pytest, I use the `pytest-mock` pytest plugin and then I access mock functionality via the `mocker` pytest fixture.  I suspect that the approach you are using may be valid in other frameworks, but is not the way things work in pytest.

While mocking with decorators and context management is great, unfortunately, in pytest this is not the way.

Instead, you'll need something like this:

`pip install pytest-mock`

and:

```
class TestExecuteApplication:  # NOTE: there's no reason to inherit from TestCase when using pytest

    def test_one(self, mocker):   # Mentioning 'mocker' brings it in as a fixture
       mocker.patch('customlib.snowflake.SnowFlakeConnector', autospec=True)
       # Now access that mocked code and write your test assertions
       # after this test function finishes, the mock patch will be undone
       assert TheThingsYouAssertForYourTest == 1234
```

Comment: More specifically, the issue is really around the fact that it is being mocked at the class level, hence persisting throughout the tests. Your approach does in fact solve the issue by isolating the mock into the explicit test(s) you want to mock. However, the closest pytest equivalent of what is being done would be like creating a fixture where the scope is `module` (or even `session` would replicate this I believe). Ultimately, a pytest way to do this would be to create a fixture with the default `function` scope. This way the test methods have better control when to mock and when to not.

Comment: Not to take away from your solution. Just adding some more information to the ***why***.

Comment: And if you inherit from testcase, why are patches kept between different test classes? I do not see that documented

Comment: In my comment to your question I linked to the section in the documentation that explains this: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#applying-the-same-patch-to-every-test-method)